# XmlSerializer serialize class contents

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I have two classes, lets call them `A` and `B`:

```
public class A
{
    public int foo;
    public int bar;
}

public class B
{
    public class A;
}
```

Now when I serialize object `B` the `XmlSerializer` is doing what you expect it to do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<B>
    <A>
        <foo>0</foo>
        <bar>0</bar>
    </A>
</B>
```

But I would need the `XmlSerializer` to serialize the contents of class `A` but ignore the root `<A>` tag, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<B>
    <foo>0</foo>
    <bar>0</bar>
</B>
```

I know I could just put the members of `A` into `B` but these are big classes and I would like that to be the last resort. I have tried to search MSDN/Google/the Internet but I just cant seem to get the wording right to find meaningful results so sorry if this has been asked before.

Is there any way to make the `XmlSerializer` not write the root tag of the class but write its members anyway?  Preferably without reorganizing classes, but if there is no other way, I will do that, too.

Comment: If you're not going to deserialize it later, how about building the object with an `XDocument` and then save that. Would that work?

Comment: That could work, I don't know why I forgot about `XDocument`... I'll take a look into that.

Comment: I wrote an [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14476099/238902) for it. Let me know if you need more info regarding it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx) and build the XML yourself.
Something like:

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(
    new XElement("B",
        new XElement("foo", a.foo),
        new XElement("bar", a.bar)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `XmlSerializer` is not that flexible -- you can tell it to ignore a property, but then it ignores it completely.

Mind you, anything you would serialize this way would be hard if not impossible to correctly deserialize again later.

Why don't you just put `foo` and `bar` as properties of `B` instead?

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the problem of deserializing it later but the code just needs to produce some XML and forget about it so deserializing is not really an issue. Good point though.

Comment: As for why I do not put `foo` and `bar` in `B`. That is because `A` is a big class and multiple classes use it, so doing that would make an even bigger mess. :D

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public class A
{
    public int foo;
    public int bar;
}

public class B
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ABetterName")]
    public A Inner;
}
```

Although this is not what you're looking for it may be preferable as it allows you to give better names to the elements